# Why is it possible to assign a const char* to a char*?

Tags: c++, string, char, literals

I know that for example `"hello"` is of type `const char*`. So my questions are:

1. How can we assign a literal string like `"hello"` to a non-`const char*` like this:

   ```
   char* s = "hello";  // "hello" is type of const char* and s is char*
                       // and we know that conversion from const char* to
                       // char* is invalid
   ```
2. Is a literal string like `"hello"`, which will take memory in all my program, or it's just like temporary variable that will get destroyed when the statement ends?

Comment: This is allowed for C compatibility only. Generally in C++ it's considered deprecated and good compilers give warning.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In fact, `"hello"` is of type `char const[6]`.

But the gist of the question is still right – why does C++ allow us to assign a read-only memory location to a non-`const` type?

The only reason for this is backwards compatibility to old C code, which didn’t know `const`. If C++ had been strict here it would have broken a lot of existing code.

That said, most compilers can be configured to *warn* about such code as deprecated, or even do so by default. Furthermore, C++11 disallows this altogether but compilers may not enforce it yet.

---

For Standerdese Fans:
<sup>[Ref 1]</sup>**C++03 Standard: §4.2/2**

> A string literal (2.13.4) that is not a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to char”; a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to wchar_t”. In either case, the result is a pointer to the first element of the array. This conversion is considered only when there is an explicit appropriate pointer target type, and not when there is a general need to convert from an lvalue to an rvalue. [**Note: this conversion is deprecated**. See Annex D. ] For the purpose of ranking in overload resolution (13.3.3.1.1), this conversion is considered an array-to-pointer conversion followed by a qualification conversion (4.4). [Example: "abc" is converted to “pointer to const char” as an array-to-pointer conversion, and then to “pointer to char” as a qualification conversion. ]

C++11 simply removes the above quotation which implies that it is illegal code in C++11.

<sup>[Ref 2]</sup>**C99 standard 6.4.5/5 "String Literals - Semantics":**

> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals. The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the array elements have type char, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character sequence; for wide string literals, the array elements have type wchar_t, and are initialized with the sequence of wide characters...
>
> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: Added the relevant quotes from the Standard.Hope you won't mind that.

Comment: MSVC in debug mode will stop you from writing to a string literal at runtime, GCC at compile time (if it can). However, there's an option, I believe that it's -wwrite-strings or such that turns on compatibility mode and puts string literals in R/W memory

Comment: @Als You’ve taken a thing of simplicity and made it ugly. ;-) But thanks. I actually wanted to add that as well but I cannot find the relevant passages in my draft of C++11 at all. 2.14.3 does define the type, and the annex specifies the invalidity of the conversion, but nothing shows that this was deprecated but valid in C++03.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ; so "hello" is char const[6] and it decays to const char * ? and also what's difference between chat const[6] and const char[6] aren't the same ?

Comment: As I understand to [deprecate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deprecate) something inherently means it was and is valid to begin with.

Comment: @Als Yes. The assignment *is* valid in C++03, only deprecated. It’s invalid in C++11.

Comment: Yes.Indeed My comment was actually reffering to yours where you said *" ...but nothing shows that this was deprecated but valid in C++03.."*

Comment: @Als Ah, misunderstanding. My “complaint” was merely that I cannot find any note in the C++11 draft noting that prior versions of C++ (i.e. ’03) had this as valid behaviour. Not surprising, since the standard doesn’t offer a complete history of C++, but that was the reason for me not to quote the standard in my answer (I don’t have the ’03 standard lying around on my current computer).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Right.I understand the confusion now.Probably one of the drafts where modifications for C++11 were suggested and accepted in the Standards committee meeting would have notes talking about the rationale but true that the final draft copy of c++11 has no wordings to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

> 2. Is a literal string like `"hello"`, which will take memory in all my program, or it's just like temporary variable that will get destroyed when the statement ends?

It is kept in program data, so it is available within lifetime of the program. You can return pointers and references to this data from the current scope.

The only reason why `const char*` is being cast to `char*` is compatibility with C, like WinAPI system calls. And this cast is made unexplicit unlike any other const casting.

Comment: so const char* is the only type that can be casted to char* unexplicitly by the compiler.?

Comment: AlexDan, `const char*` is the only type that can be cast to its non-const form (for example, `const int*` can't be cast to `int*` unexplicitly). But you can adjust the compiler to generate a waring.

Comment: also, *cast* is an irregular verb, 3 forms: *cast-cast-cast*

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `string`:

```
std::string s("hello");
```

That would be the C++ way. If you really must use `char`, you'll need to create an array and copy the contents over it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your second question is that the variable `s` is stored in RAM as type pointer-to-char.  If it's global or static, it's allocated on the heap and remains there for the life of the running program.  If it's a local ("auto") variable, it's allocated on the stack and remains there until the current function returns.  In either case, it occupies the amount of memory required to hold a pointer.

The string `"Hello"` is a constant, and it's stored as part of the program itself, along with all the other constants and initializers.  If you built your program to run on an appliance, the string would be stored in ROM.

Note that, because the string is constant and `s` is a pointer, no copying is necessary.  The pointer `s` simply points to wherever the string is stored.

Answer (score -3):

In your example, you are not assigning, but constructing. std::string, for example, does have a `std::string(const char *)` constructor (actually it's more complicated, but it doesn't matter). And, similarly, char * (if it was a type rather than a pointer to a type) could have a const char * constructor, which is copying the memory.

I don't actually know how the compiler really works here, but I think it could be similar to what I've described above: a copy of `"Hello"` is constructed in stack and `s` is initialized with this copy's address.

Comment: This is simply not correct. No copy is made, and modifying the string through the pointer is UB.

Comment: There is no copy of "Hello" on the stack! It is a string literal which will be created in some global [data segment](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Data_segment) (but this is an implementation specific detail).

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I never said that it was correct. I sad, that it could be like this. Thanks for the links anyway.