# Cutting off the end of a char *

Tags: c++, string

So i have a char *. And i want to cut off some bit at the end. So

```
char *sentence = "My name is Ted";
```

How do I cut off the Ted. I could make it a string and then use substring (coming from Java thats my go to method) but id rather not do that way. But im not sure how to do it with a char *.

EDIT: Further on the problem. The issue is in a function that takes a process and is meant to return the location when that process is started from. Thats fine i can get that. But the parameter char *procLocation is passed by reference so the location will be sent back there.

I can only get the location that includes the name of the process. I want to cut off the name of the process and just return the location. Ive tried making the location a string and doing a substring (string - length of the processName). Thats fine. But

```
procLocation = location.c_str(); // where location.substr is the location - the process name
```

gives back an error: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'char *'

Comment: “but id rather not do that way” – **why not?!** This is the way to go.

Comment: @kenny nope, you can't modify a literal.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore well I assumed he'd modify if via the sentence pointer

Comment: @kenny what do you mean?

Comment: fair enuf. I just thought itd be good to know how it was done another way. But if string is the way to go, a string it is.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore sentence[11] = '\0';

Comment: @kenny: you're still accessing constant data doing that.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Not illegal, just not guaranteed to do anything useful.

Comment: @dreamlax it's undefined behavior. Check the standard.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I know it's undefined behaviour, but it doesn't make it against the law. Undefined behaviour means just that, that the behaviour of a program will be undefined.

Comment: @dreamlax :)) In that case, I guess there's nothing you can do in C++ that is illegal, unless you program a robot to steal...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: lol yes that would be one way! But what I meant was more that if the C standard was law, it wouldn't be illegal to attempt to modify a string literal, I would probably say illegal would be a syntax error. Like ... undefined behaviour is like throwing some instructions at the computer and saying "execute", but something illegal would stop you throwing those instructions.

Answer (score 10):

Since that is a string literal, you can't modify it.

If you did:

```
char sentence[] = "My name is Ted";
```

You could simply set the character before `Ted` to `\0`.

You might be better off using `std::string` though.

Comment: I do not agree with the obligatority of your SHOULD statement

Comment: @BorisStrandjev *should* isn't the same as *must*.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: 'you might be better using...' might be better?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev He said *you* (the OP) should.  :-)

Comment: I do agree with the obligatority of your SHOULD statement.

Comment: +1: for answering and pointing out the mistakes in all the other answers!

Comment: +1. I think its the only way to shorten the string. Another is copy required string to new string and delete the old one.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev see [Key words for use in RFCs to Indicate Requirement Levels](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of cutting off your literal, you could use `std::string` constructor that copies fewer characters than is available in your `char*`:

```
const char *data = "Hello, Ted!";
string s(data, data+8);
cout << s << endl;
```

This prints `Hello, T`

This approach is less wasteful than making a `std::string` and taking a substring.

Answer (score 2):

To your original problem, as you're coming from Java, you should (should, in the sense of [RFC2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt)) definitely use `std::string`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    // copy c-string to std::string
    string arg0 = argv[0];
    cout << arg0 << endl;
    // find last occurrence of path separator
    size_t found = arg0.find_last_of("/\\");
    // split off filename part of string
    cout << arg0.substr(0,found) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Further, you should not (should not, in the sense of RFC2119) declare the `char` array as a `char` pointer, but as a `char` array:

```
char[] s0 = "Hello World!"; // <-- is better
char * s1 = "Hello World!"; // <-- avoid this
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10268716/1025391) for actual reasons why this is better. It also gives the reasons for why not to modify such rvalue strings.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged the question 'c++' and 'string' but you say you don't want to do this with `string` and `substr` ? Not sure why that is. You *should* prefer these over `char*` and C style string manipulation functions wherever possible.

To do it the C++ way:

```
string sentence = "My name is Ted";

cout << "\"" << sentence.substr(0, sentence.rfind(' ') ) << "\"" << endl;
```

Although you could (modifying your code slightly so that you have a mutable string) do this in C:

```
char sentence[] = "My name is Ted";
*strrchr(sentence, ' ') = '\0';

printf("\"%s\"\n", sentence);
```