# Initializing non-const parameter with string literal

Tags: c++, const-correctness

So I have this code:

```
class ConstTest {
public:
    explicit ConstTest(char* name) {}
};

int main() {
    ConstTest t("blarghgh");
}
```

It obviously [compiles](http://ideone.com/HNFm4G), even though I thought that it shouldn't. As string literals in C++ have type `const char[]`, and `ConstTest` constructor requires a const-less `char*` — not `const char*`. And casting a `const` pointer to a non-const one isn't something usually done by C++ implicitly.

So, where I'm wrong? Why it's compiling? Can I legally modify the dereferenced pointer inside the constructor?!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268705/c-why-is-it-possible-to-assign-a-const-char-to-a-char

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, where I'm wrong? Why it's compiling?

It is compiling because your compiler is too permissive, and your compiler is too permissive because in C++03 the implicit conversion from a string literal to `char*` was only *deprecated*, not invalid.

The rationale was backward compatibility with legacy C APIs. Per paragraph 4.2/2 of the C++03 Standard:

> A string literal (2.13.4) that is not a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to
>   `char`”; a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to `wchar_t`”. In either case,
>   the result is a pointer to the first element of the array. This conversion is considered only when there is an
>   explicit appropriate pointer target type, and not when there is a general need to convert from an lvalue to an
>   rvalue. [***Note*: this conversion is deprecated. See Annex D.**]

In C++11, however, the implicit conversion is illegal (the above paragraph has been removed altogether).

> Can I legally dereference-and-modify the pointer inside the constructor?!

You can, but you cannot modify the dereferenced object. Doing so would be undefined behavior, since the type of the object is `const`-qualified.

Comment: Yeah, I actually meant accessing the dereferenced object. Thanks for the answer!