# Constructor with a array type of another class

Tags: c++, constructor

This is the photo of the model I have to resolve:

[image]

I have this class:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

class Word
{
protected:
char *value;
char type[20];
int noChars;
static int noWords;

public:
Word(char *value, char *type)
{
    this->noChars = 0;
    this->value = new char[strlen(value) + 1];
    strcpy(this->value, value);
    strcpy(this->type, type);
    Word::noWords++;
}
Word()
{
    this->noChars = NULL;
    this->value = NULL;
    strcpy(this->type,"Nedeterminat");
}
void operator=(Word &x)
{
    this->noChars = x.noChars;
    strcpy(this->type, x.type);
    this->value = new char[strlen(x.value) + 1];
    strcpy(this->value, x.value);
}
Word(const Word& x){
    this->noChars = x.noChars;
    strcpy(this->type, x.type);
    this->value = new char[strlen(x.value) + 1];
    strcpy(this->value, x.value);   
}
char* getValue()
{
    return this->value;
}
void setType(char* x)
{
    if (x == NULL)
    {
        throw new exception("Tip gresit!");

    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(this->type, x);
    }
}
char &operator[](int i)
{
    if (i >= 0 && i <= (strlen(this->value) - 1))
    {
        return this->value[i];
    }
    else
        cout << endl << "Eroare indice: " << i;
}
static int getNoWords()
{
    return Word::noWords;
}
operator int()
{
    return this->noChars;
}
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Word&);
friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Word&);
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& consola, Word& x)
{
consola << "Value: " << x.getValue() << endl;
consola << "Type: " << x.type << endl;
consola << "NoChars: " << x.noChars << endl;
return consola;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& consola, Word& x){
cout << "Value: "; consola >> x.value;
cout << "Type: "; consola >> x.type;
cout << "NoChars: "; consola >> x.noChars;
return consola;
}
 int Word::noWords = 0;

class Dictionary{
private:
char *language;
int noWords;
bool isOnline;
Word v[100];
public:
Dictionary(char *language, Word w, int noWords, bool isOnline)  
{
    this->language = new char[strlen(language) + 1];
    strcpy(this->language, language);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        this->v[i] = w;
    }
    this->noWords = noWords;
    this->isOnline = isOnline;
}
};
int main()
{
//1
Word w1("exam", "noun");
/*Word w2;*/
Word w3 = w1;
cout << w3;
//2
cout << endl << "Word value: " << w3.getValue();
Word w2("to take", "noun");
w2.setType("verb");
//3
w3 = w2;
cout << endl << w3;
Word *pw = new Word("pointer", "noun");
delete pw;
//4
cin >> w3; cout << w3;
char character = w3[2];
cout << endl << character;
//5
double noChars = (int)w1;
cout << endl << noChars;
cout << endl << Word::getNoWords() << endl;
//6
Dictionary dictionary1("English", NULL, 0, false);
}
```

I have this main:

```
Dictionary dictionary1("English", NULL, 0, false);
```

How should I change the constructor to work? I receive a error :

```
Arrgument types are:(const char[8],int,int,bool);
```

And how should I write the default constructor?

Comment: Your class's constructor has an argument of type `Word`. What it is? Another class?

Comment: in C++ string literals decay to the type `const char*` and cannot be assigned to `char*`: change the constructor to `Dictionary(const char *language, Word w, int noWords, bool isOnline)`

Comment: @ForceBru Yes it's another class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792240/initializing-non-const-parameter-with-string-literal

Comment: @CiobanuRares-Constantin , then your second argument is wrong: you normally use `NULL` with pointers, while here `Word` isn't a pointer.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for strings? Or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for the array? Using those will make your life much simpler as a C++ programmer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg    I'm studying PO right now. I have my finals next week and I got a model of exam from  a friend. The thing is that I get the main on a paper and I'm not allowed to modify it. I can implement the classes in a way that everything will work. 

Operators, inheritage, STL(is the last exercise)

Answer (score 0):

You can not Assign null to the type `Word`. If you want to default it you should pass something like `word()`

```
Dictionary dictionary1("English", word(), 0, false);
```

**EDIT:**
The better approach,IMO, that will work for the same `main()` you have is like this:

```
class Dictionary{
private:
std::string language;
int noWords;
bool isOnline;
std::array<Word,100> v;
public:
     Dictionary(std::string const& language, Word* w, int noWords, bool isOnline): language (language),isOnline(isOnline ),noWords(noWords)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
             this->v[i] = (w==NULL)?word():*w;
         }
      }
};
```

Comment: I can't modify the main. I have to implement the classes in a way that the main works.

Comment: Well, taking an argument by `const&` just to duplicate it is inferior to taking it by value and moving to the final destination... the latter potentially even allows you to make the ctor `noexcept`, depending on `Word`.

Comment: @Deduplicator I would like to hear a bit more about it if you do not mind. cause I am still not sure why i am doing it all time :D I just see nice people doing it a lot :D

Comment: Using `std::array` you could get rid of the loop too, and replace it with a call to [`fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill). Also note that the OP have the `w` argument being not a pointer (and according to the error message `Word` is apparently an alias for `int`).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg How can I use fill with condition that if it is NULL fill with default object

Comment: You can use `fill` because the `w` argument is not a pointer in the code the OP is showing. That it's called with `NULL` is an error, it should really be `0` (if my "spider sense" is working correctly), which incidentally `NULL` is defined to in C++. And one could still use the condition `(w==NULL)?word():*w` as argument to `fill` if pointers are used (but then I would assume that it should be called with an array to begin with).

Comment: Unfortunately the OP need a class that works for the what is written in the main ..not the opposite. it kind of homework or exam ...

Comment: Well, compare passing an lvalue of `std::string`, resp. a temporary (from forwarding, conversion, or a return-value). If you accept by `const&`, you have an expensive extra copy for a temporary, if you accept by value you have a cheap extra move.

Comment: Guys I posted a photo with the subjects and what I did till now. Can you take a look please?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: `NULL` *can* be defined to `0` in C++. Or `0ULL` and many other things, or since C++11 `nullptr`.

Comment: @Deduplicator  can you look at that photo I posted? that`s the exam and you receive the main. I posted my code too. What I did till now. Can you tell me where I did wrong? I need to use a inheritage or something to make this work:  Dictionary dictionary1("English", NULL, 0, false);  ??

Comment: @Deduplicator I should have said "...*usually* is defined to...", but my main point still stands, one could easily use `std::array` instead of a plain C-style array, *and* use the `fill` method. And it doesn't matter if `w` is a pointer or not.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, it stands. There's the `std::fill` algorithm though which also works with raw arrays.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Can you check the photo I posted and the code? I edited my post. Can you take a look please?

Answer (score 0):

1. `NULL` cannot be assigned to `Word`. Try `Word()` instead which will call the default constructor to `Word`. Consider changing that function parameter to `const Word&` - anonymous temporaries are allowed to bind to `const` references.
2. I'd prefer to see a `std::string` as the type for the member variable `language`; using a `const std::string&` as the function parameter. Then you will not have to worry about a subsequent `delete` call, and defining your own assignment operators and copy constructors. *Currently, your class leaks memory.*

Comment: Yes. I know  strings = easy life. But I can't do that :))) I'm not allowed.

Comment: Well, implement (1), and fix the memory leak I allude to in (2). And either implement the copy constructor and assignment operators, or `delete` them.